# Looping back to start of script in PS

Tags: powershell

Im very green to PS and rarely need it but i have a simple Get-AdGroupMember that id like to loop back to the start of. I prefer to be able to enter enter the group name, execute the csv, then enter another unless i say no or maybe a end command. Any help appreciated

```
$GroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Group Name'
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName | select @{Label = "Full Name";Expression={$_.name}} , @{Label = "Logon Name";Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}}|
Export-csv -path C:\PS\"$GroupName"Groupmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation
Write-Host "Your file can be found in C:\PS\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple, endless loop to do this. Something like:

```
$outPath = 'C:\PS'   # an existing folder where the user has permission to create new files

while ($true) {
    $GroupName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your Group Name. Exit with blank name.'
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($GroupName)) { break }  # exit the loop

    try {
        Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $GroupName -ErrorAction Stop | 
        Select-Object @{Name = "Full Name";Expression={$_.name}},
                      @{Name = "Logon Name";Expression = {$_.sAMAccountName}} |
        Export-csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $outPath -ChildPath "$GroupName-GroupMembers.csv") -NoTypeInformation
        Write-Host "Your file can be found in $outPath"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Group '$GroupName' does not exist"
    }
    Write-Host
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly. way better than what i was attempting.